# Invalid prop `cookies` when running test with react cookies

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-cookie

I'm using [react-cookies](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie) package in my app and trying to write tests into my app. I'm trying to mock `cookie.remove` method and validate it, below are the codes:

// App.js

```
export class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    cookies: PropTypes.instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired,
  }

  handleClick() {
    // Remove data from browser cookies
    this.props.cookies.remove('data', { path: '/' });
  }
```

// Test file

```
  it('should be able to remove cookies', () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    const cookies = { remove: mockFn };
    const button = mount(<App cookies={cookies} />).find('button');
    button.props().onClick();

    expect(mockRemove).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockRemove).toHaveBeenCalledWith('data', { path: '/' });
  });
```

The test ran properly and passed, however in the console there is this warning of incorrect proptype passed into the props:

```
console.error node_modules/react/node_modules/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js:20
      Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `cookies` of type `Object` supplied to `App`, expected instance of `Cookies`.
```

How can I supply the instance of `Cookies` into my test while stubbing the `remove` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by initializing the class then modify the method, full code:

```
  it('should be able to remove cookies', () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    cookies.remove = mockFn;

    const button = mount(<App cookies={cookies} />).find('button');
    button.props().onClick();

    expect(mockRemove).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockRemove).toHaveBeenCalledWith('data', { path: '/' });
  });
```