# How to properly test the value of a cookie when using react-cookie?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test the following scenario with [JestJS](https://jestjs.io/) and need some advice on how to do it because I have no clues properly.

When I visit a page for the first time a banner appears on the bottom and contains an `Accept Cookies` button. When the user clicks the button the cookie is set using the [react-cookie](https://github.com/bendotcodes/cookies/tree/main/packages/react-cookie) package.

I need to test here the values of that cookie and check if they are the expected ones.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

jest.mock('react-cookie', () => {
    __esModule: true,
    useCookies: jest.fn()
})

const mockedUseCookies == useCookies as jest.Mock<any>

describe('Cookies Banner', () => {
    it('Cookie will get proper values after click on Accept Cookies button', () => {
        render(
            <CookiesBanner {...someCookieData}></CookiesBanner>
        )

        const acceptCookiesBtn = screen.getByTestId('acceptCookiesBtn')
        fireEvent.click(acceptCookiesBtn)

        //How do I check if the cookies have the right value here???
    })
})
```

But if I run the above test it fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies()
```

what could I be missing here?

I have checked the following posts and none fits into my scenario:

- [Invalid prop `cookies` when running test with react cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896588/invalid-prop-cookies-when-running-test-with-react-cookies)
- [Use Jest to test secure cookie value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974032/use-jest-to-test-secure-cookie-value)
- [Mocking a cookie in react-cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365446/mocking-a-cookie-in-react-cookie)

I have also checked how the tests are written for the library ([here](https://github.com/bendotcodes/cookies/blob/main/packages/react-cookie/src/__tests__/useCookies-test.js)) but again I cannot get my test to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mocked useCookies to have an implementation of jest.fn(). But the cookie banner consumes it probably  like this:

```js
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['cookie-name']);

//jest.fn returns undefined so the previous line is equivalent to:

const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = undefined;

//And then it tries to get the first, second, and the third indexed item for undefined which leads to your error "undefined is not iterable" and it is true.
```

The right solution is to mock the `react-cookie`, but it needs to have the same contract.

```js
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { useCookies } from '@testing-library/react'

//we mock it initially for all
jest.mock('react-cookie', () => {
    __esModule: true,
    useCookies: jest.fn(() => [
       // mock for cookies
       [],
       //mock for setCookie
       jest.fn(),
       //mock for removeCookie
       jest.fn()
    ])
})

const mockedUseCookies == useCookies as jest.Mock<any>

const getCookiesSpies = () => {

  const setCookieMock = jest.fn();
  const removeCookieMock = jest.fn();

  mockedUseCookies.mockImplementation(() => ([
       // mock for cookies
       [],
       //mock for setCookie
       setCookieMock,
       //mock for removeCookie
       removeCookieMock 
    ])
  ]));

  return {setCookieMock, removeCookieMock }
}

describe('Cookies Banner', () => {

   beforeEach(() => {
       // THIS IS IMPORTANT SO THAT EACH TEST IS IN ISOLATION
      jest.clearAllMocks();
   });

  it('Cookie will get proper values after click on Accept Cookies button', () => 
  {
       // OVERIDE setCookies BEFORE RENDERING !!!!

       const {setCookieMock, removeCookieMock } = getCookiesSpies();
        render(
            <CookiesBanner {...someCookieData}></CookiesBanner>
        )

        const acceptCookiesBtn = screen.getByTestId('acceptCookiesBtn')
        fireEvent.click(acceptCookiesBtn)

        //How do I check if the cookies have the right value here???
        expect(setCookieMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('expected-cookie-name', 'expected-cookie-value')
    })
  })
```

This can also be extended to inject result to the useCookies - cookie param when calling it for each test.